# store returned function value in a list WXpython

Tags: python, datetime, datepicker, wxpython

problem: when I bind my DatePicker obj with a function it works fine within that function but when I try to get that same value appended to a list in another function it does 1 or 2 things , the error would say

```
[<bound method F_Main.date_Begin of <guiwm.F_Main object at 0x08D01490>>, (15, 48, 55)]
```

which I know mean is LITERALLY calling the function so I should just add a parenthesis "()" at the end of my Function call but when I do add it I get the following error

```
date_Begin() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'
```

below is my some of my code along with the event bindings

```
self.dateBegin.Bind( wx.adv.EVT_DATE_CHANGED, self.date_Begin )
def date_Begin( self, event ):
    aStringDate = self.dateBegin.GetValue().Format("%m-%d-%y")
    print(aStringDate)
    return aStringDate
    event.Skip()
def time_Begin(self):
    aStringTime = self.timeBegin.GetTime()
    print(aStringTime)
    return aStringTime
```

and here's me calling in another function

```
def clickBtn_Generate( self, event ):
    a = self.date_Begin()
    b = self.time_Begin()
    list = []
    list.append(a)
    list.append(b)
    print(list)
    return list
    event.Skip()
```

I've tried removing and keeping the parenthesis on

```
a = self.date_Begin
```

but none of them works. Any idea how to work around this ?

```
class F_Main ( wx.Frame ):

def __init__( self, parent ):
    wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Generator", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 800,800 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

    self.SetSizeHints( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )
    self.SetForegroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_WINDOW ) )
    self.SetBackgroundColour( wx.Colour( 255, 255, 0 ) )

    bSizer5 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

    self.lbl_WS1 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Wafer Sort 1", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    self.lbl_WS1.Wrap( -1 )
    self.lbl_WS1.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_ACTIVECAPTION ) )

    bSizer5.Add( self.lbl_WS1, 0, wx.ALL, 10 )

    self.dateBegin = wx.adv.DatePickerCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultDateTime, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.adv.DP_DROPDOWN )
    bSizer5.Add( self.dateBegin, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.timeBegin = wx.adv.TimePickerCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultDateTime, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.adv.DP_DEFAULT )
    bSizer5.Add( self.timeBegin, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.dateEnd = wx.adv.DatePickerCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultDateTime, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.adv.DP_DROPDOWN )
    bSizer5.Add( self.dateEnd, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.timeEnd = wx.adv.TimePickerCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultDateTime, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.adv.DP_DEFAULT )
    bSizer5.Add( self.timeEnd, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.btnGenerate = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"MyButton", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    bSizer5.Add( self.btnGenerate, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.SetSizer( bSizer5 )
    self.Layout()

    self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

    # Connect Events
    self.dateBegin.Bind( wx.adv.EVT_DATE_CHANGED, self.date_Begin )
    #self.timeBegin.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TIME_CHANGED, self.time_Begin)
    self.dateEnd.Bind( wx.adv.EVT_DATE_CHANGED, self.date_End )
    self.timeEnd.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TIME_CHANGED, self.time_End)
    self.btnGenerate.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.clickBtn_Generate )

def __del__( self ):
    pass


# Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
def date_Begin( self, event ):
    aStringDate = self.dateBegin.GetValue().Format("%m-%d-%y")
    print(aStringDate)
    return aStringDate
    event.Skip()
def time_Begin(self):
    aStringTime = self.timeBegin.GetTime()
    print(aStringTime)
    return aStringTime

def date_End( self, event ):
    aStringDate = event.GetDate()
    event.Skip()

def time_End(self, event):
    aStringTime = event.GetDate()
    print(aStringTime)

def clickBtn_Generate( self, event ):
    a = self.date_Begin()
    b = self.time_Begin()
    list = []
    list.append(a)
    list.append(b)
    print(list)
    return list
    event.Skip()
```

Comment: The line `a = self.date_Begin()` would fail because of missing argument for `event` according to signature `date_Begin( self, event )`. Please copy & paste your code directly.

Comment: I went ahead and posted the entire code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the event.
The way around this is to send `None` instead i.e.

```
a = self.date_Begin(None)
```

Because of the way that you have coded that function, you will also need to check for an event before you make a call to `Skip()` i.e.

```
def date_Begin( self, event ):
    aStringDate = self.dateBegin.GetValue().Format("%m-%d-%y")
    print(aStringDate)
    return aStringDate
    if event:
        event.Skip()
```

---

In response to your comment about `Skip`

> Skip(self, skip=True) This method can be used inside an event handler
>   to control whether further event handlers bound to this event will be
>   called after the current one returns.
>
> Without Skip (or equivalently if Skip(false) is used), the event will
>   not be processed any more. If Skip(true) is called, the event
>   processing system continues searching for a further handler function
>   for this event, even though it has been processed already in the
>   current handler.
>
> In general, it is recommended to skip all non-command events to allow
>   the default handling to take place. The command events are, however,
>   normally not skipped as usually a single command such as a button
>   click or menu item selection must only be processed by one handler.
>
> Parameters:   skip (bool)

Comment: This works , thanks. not too sure how the skip method works it was automatically generated for me through WXFromBuilder

Comment: For information about `Skip` see my edit and/or read https://www.wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/events_overview.html